# Placement new at the union address

Tags: c++, memory-management, polymorphism, new-operator

I want to use the Placement new in my class.
To make the buffer suitable for multiple different class, I create a union member as the buffer.
The classes defined like below,

```
class MyBase
{
public:
    virtual void vFunc0(){}
    virtual void vFunc1(){}
protected:
    int memberA;
    int memberB;
};
class SubClassA:public MyBase
{
    virtual void vFunc0()override{}
    virtual void vFunc1()override{}
};

class SubClassB:public MyBase
{
    int subMemberB;
};
```

And I define a warp class

```
class WarpClass
{
public:
    WarpClass( EMySubType subType )
    {
        memset(&m_Buffer,0,sizeof(m_Buffer));
        void* pBuffer = &m_Buffer;
        switch (subType)
        {
        case ESubA:
            ::new (pBuffer) SubClassA();
            break;
        case ESubB:
            ::new (pBuffer) SubClassB();
            break;
        default:
            ::new (pBuffer) MyBase();
            break;
    }
}

private:
    union
    {
        char _b0[sizeof(MyBase)];
        char _b1[sizeof(SubClassA)];
        char _b2[sizeof(SubClassB)];
    }m_Buffer;
};
```

Because the project I work on has no memeory managerment, I want to create a static array can suit a series class and subclasses, and I thought up this way to warp them all.

So will it cause any problem in this way? Or is there a better way to define a safe buffer for the Placement new?

Comment: Also, stack overflow isn't a good place for a code review.   SO questions should be specific technical questions with an objective answer (as opposed to "well, you could do X or Y or Z depending on what you like more").   https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a better fit for this question.

Comment: how about std::aligned_union? en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_union

Comment: Looks like trying to reinvent the wheel. With c++14 you can enjoy std::variant. it provides the functionality you are seeking. On older platforms, you can try boost::variant.

Comment: @Red.Wave variant is 17 not 14 and adds even more memory overhead.   Not ideal if you don't need the additional functionality that memory provides.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant